# Pojo to Pojo Transformation using DataWeave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I am trying to use DataWeave for Pojo to Pojo transformation.  This works fine but the output is always a LinkedHashMap.  I tried coercing this to an object but still get the same output. Is there a way to seamlessly convert the LinkedHashMap to the desired Pojo representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 'class' metadata key as hint for what class needs to be created and sent in. If this is not explicitly defined, DataWeave will try to infer from the context or it will assign it the default values, HashMap and ArrayList:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    id: "xxx"
} as :object{
    class : "com.test.Product"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan - used that approach but the result is still the same.

Comment: Updated. removed the 'product:' before which forces a map. Please provide your weave code if you are still having issue

Comment: This should work for you.  It might read a bit better if you pull the type information up to a %type header like so: %type product = :object { class: "com.test.Product" } .  Then you can just append "as :product" to coerce it to a Product instance.